# Prevent links in standalone web apps opening Mobile Safari with modals on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I'm making an application and I'd like to have the standalone look on mobile devices.

I've used

```
 // Mobile Safari in standalone mode
if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone){

    // If you want to prevent remote links in standalone web apps opening Mobile Safari, change 'remotes' to true
    var noddy, remotes = false;

    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        noddy = event.target;

        // Bubble up until we hit link or top HTML element. Warning: BODY element is not compulsory so better to stop on HTML
        while(noddy.nodeName !== "A" && noddy.nodeName !== "HTML") {
            noddy = noddy.parentNode;
        }

        if('href' in noddy && noddy.href.indexOf('http') !== -1 && (noddy.href.indexOf(document.location.host) !== -1 || remotes))
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.location.href = noddy.href;
        }

    },false);
}
```

However I'm also using modals in my application. The previous JS will break the code for the modal.

JS Modal:

```
$ ->
  modal_holder_selector = '#modal-holder'
  modal_selector = '.modal'

  $(document).on 'click', 'a[data-modal]', ->
    location = $(this).attr('href')
    #Load modal dialog from server
    $.get location, (data)->
      $(modal_holder_selector).html(data).
      find(modal_selector).modal()
    false

  $(document).on 'ajax:success',
    'form[data-modal]', (event, data, status, xhr)->
      url = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location')
      if url
        # Redirect to url
        window.location = url
      else
        # Remove old modal backdrop
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove()

        # Replace old modal with new one
        $(modal_holder_selector).html(data).
        find(modal_selector).modal()

      false
```

Could someone help me combining these two?

Comment: Can you add you html also? Your JS Modal 'click' probably gets prevented, depends on your `href`value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that the you get redirected to the page directly, instead of that page being opened inside the modal.

Since your current "standalone" code looks pretty custom, I'll assume you can enhance it to fit your needs. If that's not the case, let me know.

Try changing your conditional that triggers the redirect, by also checking for the `data-modal` attribute:

```
if('href' in noddy && !'data-modal' in noddy && noddy.href.indexOf('http') !== -1 && (noddy.href.indexOf(document.location.host) !== -1 || remotes)) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    document.location.href = noddy.href;
}
```

Since the conditional is getting pretty long (and could change), you could abstract it away (`shouldRedirect()` or `isModal()` or something), but I'll leave that up to you.